# Azure Pipeline Yaml Error: The current operating system is not capable of running this task

Tags: azure-devops

below is the task I have written to copy files to my Azure blob, it works fine with Windows but for mac and linux it gives me error as "The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only" How could I fix this?

The Yaml task where I get the error:

```
strategy:
          matrix:
            win:
              imageName:            'windows-2019'
              RootSuffix:           'x64-windows-staticlib'
              osSuffix:             'windows'
              LibFT4222Suffix:      'windows'
              matlabVersion:        '9.6.0-2'
              extraCmakeOptions:    ''
            mac:
              imageName:            'macOS-10.15'
              RootSuffix:           'x64-osx'
              osSuffix:             'osx'
              LibFT4222Suffix:      'x64-osx'
              matlabVersion:        '9.5.0'
              extraCmakeOptions:    ''
            linux:
              imageName:            'ubuntu-18.04'
              RootSuffix:           'x64-linux'
              osSuffix:             'linux'
              LibFT4222Suffix:      'linux'
              matlabVersion:        '9.5.0'
              extraCmakeOptions:    ''

        pool:
          vmImage: $(imageName)
```

And the task:

```
 task: AzureFileCopy@2
          displayName: 'Publish ABC to Blob'
          inputs:
            SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ABC-$(osSuffix)'
            azureSubscription: 'Azure CICD'
            Destination: AzureBlob
            storage: '$(BlobStorageAccount)'
            ContainerName: '$(BlobContainer)'
            BlobPrefix: '$(BlobPrefix)/ABC/$(DeploymentVersion)'
            AdditionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: '/V /S'
            outputStorageUri: BlobUri
            outputStorageContainerSasToken: BlobSASToken
```

Comment: can you try with AzureFileCopy@4 ? maybe fixed in later version.

Comment: it fails with AzureFileCopy@4  as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) is written in PowerShell and thus works **only** when run on **Windows** agents. If your pipelines require Linux agents and need to copy files to an Azure Storage Account, consider running `az storage blob` commands in the [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) as an alternative.

Comment: can you please tell what should be in ps script which I see as a parameter for Azure CLI task . i am new to this devops thing and I am trying to modify an existing pipeline with a task of adding artifacts to blob storage.